# In R: addDataFrame Excel package function

Tags: r

When I create an Excel workbook using addDataFrame function to add my dataset, then I get automatically an extra column displayed in Excel which indeed count the number of observations of the dataset.
Let say my dataset is 1 column dataset as:
My1stCol: val1 val2 val3

Then in Excel I'll get 2 columns:

**The extra column added with values: 1 2 3**
My1stCol: val1 val2 val3

How can I get rid of the automatically added column  1,2,3 information in excel that I don't need ?
Looking forward to your reply

Comment: [`row.names = FALSE`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/xlsx/versions/0.6.4.2/topics/addDataFrame)

Comment: Can you share the code that you've been using?